# Kendo script defined on _Layout wont work on View

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm learning to work with Kendo UI.

I tried to launch a grid, if I refer to the script on the view page it works.

Below, the View page code. All the other kendo scripts placed on the _Layout file work fine, I can use other kendo components, such as ComboBox. The only one that does not work is the kendo.all.min

**View**

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<head>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.2.616/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>

<p>Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>

<div id="grid"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var data = [{
        firstName: "Mauricio",
        lastName: "Silva",
        email: "mauricio@email.com"
    },
    {
        firstName: "Daniel",
        lastName: "Silva",
        email: "daniel@email.com"
    },
    {
        firstName: "Janaina",
        lastName: "Silva",
        email: "janaina@email.com"
    }];

    $("#grid").kendoGrid(
        { dataSource: data }
    );

</script>
```

[image: Works Perfectly]

***But*** if I try to add this script to the Layout file, it stops working.

**_Layout**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - TesteKendo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />

    @*Add Kendo Files*@
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.2.616/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.2.616/styles/kendo.blueopal.min.css" />
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.2.616/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.2.616/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">TesteKendo</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="TestarGridRemoteDataBinding">Grid - RDB</a>
                        </li>                        
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2021 - TesteKendo - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Not Working]

Don't know where the problem is, since I followed strictly the tutorial!

Comment: What errors are showing in the browser's developer tools Console window?

Comment: Looks like you are loading jquery twice. Kendo bundling described here: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/hosting-kendoui

Comment: I'm gonna correct and try it again. Ynhks

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Concert+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,400i,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Ev.Town</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="menu-bg">
        <div class="menu">
            
            <div class="menu-logo">
                <a href="#">Ev.Town</a>
            </div>
            
            <nav class="menu-nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Criar Evento</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Soluções</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
                    <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section class="newsletter">
        <div class="newsletter-info">
            <h1>Newsletter</h1>
            <p>assine e fique por dentro das novidades</p>
        </div>
        <form class="newsletter-form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Seu e-mail">
            <button type="submit">Assinar</button>
        </form>
    </section>  
</body>
</html>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Concert+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,400i,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Ev.Town</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="menu-bg">
        <div class="menu">
            
            <div class="menu-logo">
                <a href="#">Ev.Town</a>
            </div>
            
            <nav class="menu-nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Criar Evento</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Soluções</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
                    <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>

    <h1 class="slogan">Entenda o seu público, Conheça o seu negócio</h1>

    <section class="sobre" id="sobre">
        <div class="sobre-info">
            <h1>Conheça <br> seu público</h1>
            <p>
                Lorem Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado.                 
            </p>

            <p>
                A erat nam at lectus urna duis convallis. A condimentum vitae sapien pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus. Nam at lectus urna 
                duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum. A erat nam at lectus urna duis. Vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales.                 
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="sobre-img">
            <img src="img/planta.png" alt="planta">
        </div>
                
    </section>

    <section class="solucoes" id="solucoes">
        <h1>Soluções</h1>
        <div class="solucoes-container">
            <div class="solucoes-item pagamento">
                <h2>Pagamento</h2>
                <img src="img/pagto_cel.jpg" alt="pagamento celular">
                <p>
                    A erat nam at lectus urna duis convallis. A condimentum vitae sapien.
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="solucoes-item insights">
                <h2>Insights</h2>
                <img src="img/insight.jpg" alt="Insights">
                <p>
                    A erat nam at lectus urna duis convallis. A condimentum vitae sapien pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus. 
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="solucoes-item integracao">
                <h2>Integração</h2>
                <img src="img/integrador.jpg" alt="Integração">
                <p>
                    A erat nam at lectus urna duis convallis. A condimentum vitae sapien pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus. Nam at lectus urna 
                    duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum. A erat nam at lectus urna duis. Vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales.                 
                </p>                
            </div>
        </div>        
    </section>

    <section class="planos" id="planos">
        <div class="planos-item">
            <h2>Starter</h2>
            <span><sup>R$</sup>100/mensal</span>
            <ul>
                <li>Dados de tráfego</li>
                <li>Insights</li>
                <li>Controlador de acesso</li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#">Solicitar Orçamento</a>
        </div>

        <div class="planos-item">
            <h2>Professional</h2>
            <span><sup>R$</sup>1500/anual</span>
            <ul>
                <li>Benefícios Starter</li>
                <li>Sistema de pagamento</li>
                <li>Suporte 24hr</li>
                <li>Aluguel de PDV</li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#">Solicitar Orçamento</a>
        </div>

        <div class="planos-item">
            <h2>Platinum</h2>
            <span><sup>R$</sup>5000</span>
            <ul>
                <li>Benefícios Professional</li>
                <li>Análises detalhadas</li>
                <li>Relatórios Personalizados</li>
                <li>Benefícios no App</li>                
                <li>Desconto para usuários**</li>                
            </ul>
            <a href="#">Solicitar Orçamento</a>
        </div>        
    </section>

    <section class="beneficios" id="beneficios">
        <div class="beneficios-item">
            <h2>Inteligente</h2>
            <p>Buscamos estar sempre um passo a frente. 
            Com o Ev.Town o fluxo de caixa do seu evento poderá
            ser gerenciado em uma única ferramenta</p>
        </div>
        <div class="beneficios-item">
            <h2>Intuitivo</h2>
            <p>Com uma interface pensada no usuário, o Ev.Town
            é super intuitivo. Mas em caso de dúvida temos um time humanizado pra 
            te auxiliar</p>
        </div>
        <div class="beneficios-item">
            <h2>Integrador</h2>
            <p>Sabemos que cada lojista pode ter o seu ERP. Sendo assim
            criamos um sistema inteligente de integração. Disponibilizamos
            APIs de integração. Caso necessário, também fornecemos aluguel 
            de PDVs na nuvem              
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="beneficios-item">
            <h2>Adaptável</h2>
            <p>Atender as mudanças é uma forma de estar a frente.
            Sentiu falta de alguma funcionalidade? Entre em contato 
            conosco. Estamos sempre dispostos a ouvir idéias e implantar
            melhorias  
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="beneficios-item">
            <h2>Prático</h2>
            <p>Atender as mudanças é uma forma de estar a frente.
            Sentiu falta de alguma funcionalidade? Entre em contato 
            conosco. Estamos sempre dispostos a ouvir idéias e implantar
            melhorias  
            </p>
        </div>                
        <div class="beneficios-item">
            <h2>Rápido</h2>
            <p>Atender as mudanças é uma forma de estar a frente.
            Sentiu falta de alguma funcionalidade? Entre em contato 
            conosco. Estamos sempre dispostos a ouvir idéias e implantar
            melhorias  
            </p>
        </div>                
    </section>

    <section class="newsletter">
        <div class="newsletter-info">
            <h1>Newsletter</h1>
            <p>assine e fique por dentro das novidades</p>
        </div>
        <form class="newsletter-form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Seu e-mail">
            <button type="submit">Assinar</button>
        </form>
    </section>  
</body>
</html>


body, h1, h2, p, ul, li, a {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body {
    font-family: "Nunito", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #222222;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}



ul {
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* menu */
.menu {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 15px 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    /* align-items: center; */
    border-bottom: solid 2px #ce9a94;
}

.menu a {
    color: #DF4A3A;
}

.menu-logo a {
    font-family: 'Concert One', cursive;
    font-weight: bold;    
    line-height: 35px;
    color: #DF4A3A;
    font-size: 3em;
    margin: 0 10px; /*colocar um espaço das bordas*/    
}

.menu-nav ul {    
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;    
}

.menu-nav a {
    font-size: 1.25em;
    font-family: 'Concert One', cursive;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
}

.menu-nav a:hover {
    color: #5E2019;
}

/*slogan*/

.slogan {
    max-width: 960px;
    font-size: 3.5em;
    line-height: 1;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 60px 10px;
    color: #5E2019;
}

/* sobre */
.sobre {
    border-top: 2px solid #5E2019;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #5E2019;
    display: flex;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 60px 10px;  
    align-items: center;  
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.sobre-info {
    flex: 2 1 300px;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

.sobre-info h1 {
    color: #DF4A3A;
    font-size: 3em;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}

.sobre-info p {
    color: #5E2019;  
    line-height: 1.4em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
.sobre-info img {
    flex: 1 1 160px;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

/* solucoes */
.solucoes {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 60px auto;
    color: #5E2019;
}

.solucoes h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
    margin: 0 10px 60px 10px;        
}

.solucoes h1::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 4em;
    height: .05em;
    background-color: #5E2019;
    
}

.solucoes-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;    
}

.solucoes-item {
    background-color: #df4b3a54;
    color: #5E2019;
    flex: 1 1 175px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 15px;
    max-width: 300px;    
    border-top: 8px solid;        
}

.solucoes-item p {
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-size: 1.25em;
}

.solucoes-item h2 {
    font-size: 2em;
    background-color: #df4b3a17;
    border-radius: 0.2em;
    padding: 60px 20px;   
    text-align: center;
}

/* planos */

.planos {
    max-width: 960x;
    background-color: #df4b3a17;
    padding: 60px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.planos-item {
    flex: 1 1 260px;
    border: 4px solid #5e20191c;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
}


.planos-item h2 {
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #DF4A3A;
    text-align: center;
}

.planos-item span {
    max-width: 300px;
    color: #5E2019;
    margin: 20px auto;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0 5px 0;
    font-size: 1.35em;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #df4b3a91;
    border-top: 3px solid #df4b3a91;
}

.planos-item sup {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.planos-item ul {
    max-width: 300px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    font-size: 1.15em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #5E2019;
    font-style: italic;    
}

.planos-item li {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 15px;    

}

.planos-item li::after{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    background: #DF4A3A;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.planos-item a {
    max-width: 300px;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border: 3px solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color:#DF4A3A;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: bold;    
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 15px 0;
}

.beneficios {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 60px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.beneficios-item {
    flex: 1 1 2500px;
    margin: 20px 10px;
    color: #5E2019;
    max-width: 300px;
}

.beneficios-item h2 {
    font-size: 2em;    
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.beneficios-item h2::before {
     content: '';
     display: inline-block;
     width: 6px;
     height: 23px;
     background-color: #DF4A3A;
     margin-right: 10px;

}

.newsletter {
    background: #df4b3a21;
    padding: 60px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    color: #5E2019
}

.newsletter-info {
    flex: 1 1 260px;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

.newsletter-info h1 {
    font-size: 2.25em;
}

.newsletter-info p {
    font-size: 1.25em;
    font-style: italic;
    max-width: 230px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.newsletter-form {
    flex: 2 1 200px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    align-self: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}


.newsletter-form input {
    flex: 3 1 200px;
    max-width: 220px;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    color: #DF4A3A;
    font-style: italic;
    border: 4px solid #DF4A3A;
    background: transparent;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    border-radius: 0px;
    height: 60px;
}

.newsletter-form button {
    flex: 1 1 200px;
    max-width: 220px;
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #DF4A3A;
    color: white;
    margin: 0 10px 10 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 15px 10px;
}

/*Footer*/

.footer {
    display: flex;
    height: 200px;
    align-items: center;
    height: 130px;
}

.footer p {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: white;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .newsletter-form button {
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }
}


@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .planos {
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }
    
    .beneficios-item {
        text-align: center;
    }
}


/* login.html */

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 500px;
    max-width: 800px;
    /* border: 3px solid #5E2019; */
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-color: #df4b3a18;
}

.form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1 1 400px;
    width: 50%;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #df4b3a09;
    color: #5E2019;
}

.form h2 {
    font-size: 2.25rem;
    margin: 40px;
    color: #DF4A3A;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.form  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#5E2019;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.form  a:hover {
    color: #DF4A3A;
}

.box {
    padding: 12px;
    width: 65%;
    margin: 15px;    
    border: 2px solid #5E2019;
    border-radius: 20px;
    outline: none;  
}

#submit {
    padding: 12px 30px;    
    max-width: 200px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    flex-shrink: 200px;
    background-color:#5E2019;
    color:white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.05em;
    font-weight: bold;    
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 15px 0;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#submit:hover {
    cursor: pointer;    
    color: #DF4A3A;
}

/* right side */

.side {
    display: flex;    
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50%;
}

.side img {
    max-width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    flex: 1 1 160px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .side img {
        height: 0;
    }
}
```